# Opiniones sobre logger

Tags: java, logger

En mi programa utilizo BBDD, entonces se me ha ocurrido guardar los logs de errores en la propia base de datos, sin embargo aquí se me presentan 3 dudas:

1. Qué hacer si el error a registrar sucede en la propia conexión a la BBDD, donde se registraría un error de conexión a la BBDD.
2. El mismo dilema sucedería si guardo los logs en archivos. Donde se registra un error de log si los errores de logs se registran en archivos txt y resulta que el error sucede en el propio acceso o escritura en dicho archivo.
3. Qué pasa si es el propio logger el que genera el error a logear. Sea donde sea que esté programado de donde llevar el log.

El logger que uso es el de java.util.logging.

Intento evitar archivos si es posible, y trabajar única y exclusivamente con BBDD, pero si fuese más óptimo usar archivos, pues lo haría.

¿Qué opinan de usar la BBDD como primera preferencia para guardar los logs, y en caso de error usar archivos de log?(Los 2 medios a la vez sería super-raro que fallasen) ¿Es buena opción esa?

Comment: Esta es una pregunta totalmente basada en opiniones.. ahora mi primera pregunta seria.. que te hace pensar que el sistema de archivos del sistema operativo no es una base de datos?? o que una base de datos no es un sistema de archivos? o que todo es propenso a error y llega un punto que no lo podes controlar?

Comment: Tené en cuenta que un error en el sistema de archivos es mucho menos frecuente que un error en la base de datos. Por otro lado, en una base de datos corres el riesgo de estar logueando lo que hacés dentro de una transacción. Si por un motivo de lógica de negocio se hace rollback, perderias esos logs. Y por último también tenes la opción de loguear a otro sistema e implementar redundancia etc.

Answer (score 1):

En primera instancia, un sistema de *logging* debe ser poco propenso a errores (del tipo FS, IO, concurrencias, ...).

El caso de que un sistema de *logging* tenga como *target* una base de datos no es del todo una buena idea*. La cantidad de trabajo en un sistema de este estilo es muy alta, por lo que al estar apuntando a una base de datos está literalmente tomando como rehén una conexión del *pool* de conexiones.

*Los sistemas de *logging* que apuntan a bases de datos tienen bastante más ingeniería que, por ejemplo, un sistema de *logging* que apunte al *file system*. Requiere una buena arquitectura y un buen *DBA* (*Database Administration*), para tener en cuenta una tensión en las comunicaciones.

Supongamos el caso de que el sistema de *logging* tiene como *target* el *file system*, lo cual es un escenario muy común. Si bien es cierto que la escritura a ficheros está muy sujeta a errores, es algo con lo que se pueda convivir. Por lo general, un error en el sistema de *logging* suele escalar a un *crash* en la aplicación.

Si tu aplicación debe tener un sistema de notificación muy crítico (es decir, todos y cada uno de los errores deben ser sí o sí notificados) y esto incluye principalmente errores en el sistema de *logging* (el cual es el más crítico y sujeto a errores no notificados), debes sobreimplementar dicho sistema con una arquitectura de *audit*.
Normalmente, en este tipo de aplicaciones, el *logging* tiene una segunda vía llamada los *audits*. Esa segunda vía puede ser usada o bien siempre (se *loggea* por duplicado) o sólo en caso de que el *logging* principal tenga algún tipo de problema.

Por ejemplo, podrías tener un *logging* en ficheros y su *audit* por *MQTT*, *Slack* o en la misma base de datos. En caso de estar *loggeando* a una base de datos, otra opción sería auditar a un *provider* distinto (por ejemplo, escribir *logs* a *MySQL* y auditar a *PostgreSQL*).